# ClassNotFoundException when making all loggers asynchronous in Log4j under OSGi

Tags: java, logging, log4j, osgi, log4j2

`ClassNotFoundException` always occurs when I try to make all Log4j loggers asynchronous on an OSGi environment. It seems to be an issue related to `ClassLoader`.

Activator's code:

```
public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    Activator.context = bundleContext;

    System.setProperty("log4j.ignoreTCL", "false"); // Also tried "true"
    System.setProperty("Log4jContextSelector", "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector");

    LoggerContext loggerContext = LogManager.getContext(); // Exception occurs here

    return;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector cannot be found by org.apache.logging.log4j.api_2.8.2
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.loadClass(LoaderUtil.java:141)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newInstanceOf(LoaderUtil.java:180)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newCheckedInstanceOf(LoaderUtil.java:201)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.newCheckedInstanceOfProperty(LoaderUtil.java:226)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.createContextSelector(Log4jContextFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:94)
    at teste.Activator.start(Activator.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Start Levels

```
Plugin                          Start Level
==============================  ===========
com.lmax.disruptor              1
org.apache.logging.log4j.core   1
org.apache.logging.log4j.api    2
mybundle                        3
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: We also got this exception when using new relic along side Log4j2 (2.13.0)

Comment: Still having this issue in log4j v2.20.0 
Gets stuck in debug mode every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Log4j 2 bug. I've opened an issue to Apache [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1936) and posted a [workaround](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1936?focusedCommentId=16070572&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16070572).